# how to resgist datamapper mediator in WSO2 ei

Tags: wso2

Now I want to use data mapper mediator in WSO2 ei console, and it requires me to select some Configuration Registry files:

[image: Link to image]

but I don't know how to register these configuration, in the WSO2 EI documentation I could hardly find how to register, while I only found that I can create a ESB solution project and package that to a `.car` file, then deploy it.
But I don't want to do this, so I need help.

Comment: can you try to provide what have you done so far?

Comment: I tried to do these steps below:
1. I create a data mapper mediator in WSO2 EI manager which is another way creating in WSO2 tools
2. then I need to select the configurations, there were 3 items to fill, which is Mapping Configuration, Input Schema, Output Schema, and I 
each item had two choice to select: Configuration, Governance Registry,
when I opened one of the choices, it showed a list of directories, it seemed like I need to have register the configuration, but the problem is that I hadn't register any configuration, so I want to know where I can register the configurations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is in [this link](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI600/Data+Mapper+Mediator).

> **Mapping Configuration:**    The file, which contains the script file that is used to execute the mapping. You need to create a mapping
>   configuration file using the Dev Studio-based Tooling plugin, and
>   store it either in the Configuration Registry or Governance Registry,
>   to select and upload it from here.

Let me know if it worked or need more help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I have already created a mapping configuration file using the Dev Studio,  and I know it will generate configuration files in the Registry project which is a part of the ESB solution project. 
But the question is how could I upload these files to the WSO2 EI, the only way I know is packaging the ESB solution and deploy it, do you konw any other ways to upload these files?
Thanks!

Comment: I red the documentation again, and now I know the only way to upload the registry files is deploy the registry project!